# Set destination on comment post

Tags: 7, comments

Short question:
How do you modify the destination on comment post?

Long question:
Say, my comment limit is set to 10 per page. When I post the 11th comment, Drupal takes me to /node/#?page-1#comment-#. Instead, I want it to take me to the node it was posted to, i.e. /node/#.

I need this because I'm using the [More Comments](http://drupal.org/project/morecomments) module, which doesn't use pagers and not compatible with permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out how to manually set the destination on comment post, but I did found the [Comment Goodness](http://drupal.org/project/comment_goodness) module that works with [More Comments](http://drupal.org/project/morecomments), to remove the ?page-1#comment-# query. And this solves my question.